# How to iterate through Response from Twitter Search API

Tags: c#, json, twitter, json.net

I am using the following code which works on the

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?

but doesn't work on the Search URL which is:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=kifi%20sales

The code is:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    JToken statuses = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JToken>();
    Console.WriteLine("Most recent statuses from home timeline twitter account for the given search:");
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (var status in statuses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", status["text"]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The error I get is `Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty` in other words it can't see the "text" property .

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [Search API has a subtly different response](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) from the `home_timeline` API.

```
{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "coordinates": null,
      "favorited" ...
```

I'd suggest using a library to make things as transparent as possible.

Comment: Hi, its probably not clear from my post I was actually asking what the foreach loop code should be (once I put statuses into a JToken).